# How to use webform to register a new user on Drupal 8/9 and link to contact in CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, drupal-8

I have a need to use Webform (using the Webform CiviCRM module) in Drupal 8 to register a new user and their organisation in Civi and at the same time create the user account in Drupal and link it to the Civi contact. I can't use the standard Drupal register form as I want to include their organisation and other custom fields. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Using Webform and Webform CiviCRM modules create a webform with the fields required for the user and their organisation to create the contact and organisation in CiviCRM.

Then create a WebformHandler to programmatically create the user using the postSave() function. The WebformHandler is a single php file that needs to be saved in a custom module folder as:
`my_module/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/CreateUserHandler.php`
I have created a basic guideline WebformHandler that creates the user and connects to the CiviContact at https://gist.github.com/bmango/0347f6c22b3fb38e34be57bb50f8e99e

Note that the namespace declaration at the top of the script is not the same as the path to the file but will be:

`namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\WebformHandler;`

omitting the 'src'.

Once you have created the WebformHandler it should appear on the Webform "Email/Handlers" tab where you can then add it to the form.

This answer extends the [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245097/2369) given by mAtZ to [Create a new user on Webform submission](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/243757/create-a-new-user-on-webform-submission), by adding the code to connect the Drupal user account to the Civi contact.

Answer (score 4):

Ben's answer sounds like a really good extra tool for this. Just for the record other solutions include

- using Tags and CMS User extension https://github.com/Skvare/com.skvare.cmsuser
- Drupal Rules eg https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/pull/273/files

Comment: Thanks for giving some alternative solutions :)

Comment: So the workflow with the skvar extension is: Webform to create Contact with Group X or Tag Y --> chron to execute CMSUser --> CMSUser scans for Group-X or Tag-Y contacts and creates Drupal user then clears the X and Y so as to not repeat it.  Is that right?